# Mongodb GUI on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu-16.04, mongodb-3.6

I wonder whether there is GUI associated with `mongodb 3.6` that allows to manage the database from interfaces. If yes, how to install it on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Did you even try to search for this? Anyway, you can use Robo3t if you can find plenty of explanations online for how to install it on ubuntu

Comment: I tried to install Robo3t, but it does not work. When I run the robo3t bin I get this error : This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt plateform plugin "xcb"

Comment: NoSQLBooster is really good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

The solution consist simply on deleting `libstdc++.so.6` and `libstdc++.so.6.0.22` from lib folder